# HTML table span element hiding/deleting using styles

Tags: html, css, wordpress, html-table

Morning,

I'm working on automatic generated wordpress website product page for e-commerce. The page is generated with span element in the table which adds extra space between the header and button in the table. Whenever user select one of the buttons, the name of the button he select is shown in this space.

As far as I can tell there is no way to disable this feature from anywhere of the wordpress menu. That's why I'm trying to disable it in the code.

[image]

Pic 1. Original setup, none selected

[image]

Pic 2. Original setup, buttons selected

```
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="label"><label for="chest-size">Chest Size</label><span class="woo-selected-variation-item-name" data-default=""></span></td>
                    <td class="value woo-variation-items-wrapper"><select id="chest-size" class=" hide woo-variation-raw-select woo-variation-raw-type-button" style="display:none" name="attribute_chest-size" data-attribute_name="attribute_chest-size" data-show_option_none="yes"><option value="">Choose an option</option><option value="M(90-99cm)" class="attached enabled">M(90-99cm)</option><option value="L(100-110cm)" class="attached enabled">L(100-110cm)</option><option value="XL(110-120cm)" class="attached enabled">XL(110-120cm)</option></select><ul role="radiogroup" aria-label="Chest Size" class="variable-items-wrapper button-variable-wrapper" data-attribute_name="attribute_chest-size" data-attribute_values="[&quot;M(90-99cm)&quot;,&quot;L(100-110cm)&quot;,&quot;XL(110-120cm)&quot;]"><li aria-checked="false" data-wvstooltip="M(90-99cm)" class="variable-item button-variable-item button-variable-item-M(90-99cm)" title="M(90-99cm)" data-title="M(90-99cm)" data-value="M(90-99cm)" role="radio" tabindex="0"><div class="variable-item-contents"><span class="variable-item-span variable-item-span-button">M(90-99cm)</span></div></li><li aria-checked="false" data-wvstooltip="L(100-110cm)" class="variable-item button-variable-item button-variable-item-L(100-110cm)" title="L(100-110cm)" data-title="L(100-110cm)" data-value="L(100-110cm)" role="radio" tabindex="0"><div class="variable-item-contents"><span class="variable-item-span variable-item-span-button">L(100-110cm)</span></div></li><li aria-checked="false" data-wvstooltip="XL(110-120cm)" class="variable-item button-variable-item button-variable-item-XL(110-120cm)" title="XL(110-120cm)" data-title="XL(110-120cm)" data-value="XL(110-120cm)" role="radio" tabindex="0"><div class="variable-item-contents"><span class="variable-item-span variable-item-span-button">XL(110-120cm)</span></div></li></ul>                     </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="label"><label for="height">Height</label><span class="woo-selected-variation-item-name" data-default=""></span></td>
                    <td class="value woo-variation-items-wrapper"><select id="height" class=" hide woo-variation-raw-select woo-variation-raw-type-button" style="display:none" name="attribute_height" data-attribute_name="attribute_height" data-show_option_none="yes"><option value="">Choose an option</option><option value="Regular(170-179cm)" class="attached enabled">Regular(170-179cm)</option><option value="Long(180-189cm)" class="attached enabled">Long(180-189cm)</option></select><ul role="radiogroup" aria-label="Height" class="variable-items-wrapper button-variable-wrapper" data-attribute_name="attribute_height" data-attribute_values="[&quot;Regular(170-179cm)&quot;,&quot;Long(180-189cm)&quot;]"><li aria-checked="false" data-wvstooltip="Regular(170-179cm)" class="variable-item button-variable-item button-variable-item-Regular(170-179cm)" title="Regular(170-179cm)" data-title="Regular(170-179cm)" data-value="Regular(170-179cm)" role="radio" tabindex="0"><div class="variable-item-contents"><span class="variable-item-span variable-item-span-button">Regular(170-179cm)</span></div></li><li aria-checked="false" data-wvstooltip="Long(180-189cm)" class="variable-item button-variable-item button-variable-item-Long(180-189cm)" title="Long(180-189cm)" data-title="Long(180-189cm)" data-value="Long(180-189cm)" role="radio" tabindex="0"><div class="variable-item-contents"><span class="variable-item-span variable-item-span-button">Long(180-189cm)</span></div></li></ul><a class="reset_variations" href="#" style="visibility: hidden;">Clear</a>                      </td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
```

Code for the original setup

[image]

Pic 3. Output when span element is cut out from the code

```
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="label"><label for="chest-size">Chest Size</label></td>
                    <td class="value woo-variation-items-wrapper"><select id="chest-size" class=" hide woo-variation-raw-select woo-variation-raw-type-button" style="display:none" name="attribute_chest-size" data-attribute_name="attribute_chest-size" data-show_option_none="yes"><option value="">Choose an option</option><option value="M(90-99cm)" class="attached enabled">M(90-99cm)</option><option value="L(100-110cm)" class="attached enabled">L(100-110cm)</option><option value="XL(110-120cm)" class="attached enabled">XL(110-120cm)</option></select><ul role="radiogroup" aria-label="Chest Size" class="variable-items-wrapper button-variable-wrapper" data-attribute_name="attribute_chest-size" data-attribute_values="[&quot;M(90-99cm)&quot;,&quot;L(100-110cm)&quot;,&quot;XL(110-120cm)&quot;]"><li aria-checked="false" data-wvstooltip="M(90-99cm)" class="variable-item button-variable-item button-variable-item-M(90-99cm)" title="M(90-99cm)" data-title="M(90-99cm)" data-value="M(90-99cm)" role="radio" tabindex="0"><div class="variable-item-contents"><span class="variable-item-span variable-item-span-button">M(90-99cm)</span></div></li><li aria-checked="false" data-wvstooltip="L(100-110cm)" class="variable-item button-variable-item button-variable-item-L(100-110cm)" title="L(100-110cm)" data-title="L(100-110cm)" data-value="L(100-110cm)" role="radio" tabindex="0"><div class="variable-item-contents"><span class="variable-item-span variable-item-span-button">L(100-110cm)</span></div></li><li aria-checked="false" data-wvstooltip="XL(110-120cm)" class="variable-item button-variable-item button-variable-item-XL(110-120cm)" title="XL(110-120cm)" data-title="XL(110-120cm)" data-value="XL(110-120cm)" role="radio" tabindex="0"><div class="variable-item-contents"><span class="variable-item-span variable-item-span-button">XL(110-120cm)</span></div></li></ul>                     </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="label"><label for="height">Height</label></td>
                    <td class="value woo-variation-items-wrapper"><select id="height" class=" hide woo-variation-raw-select woo-variation-raw-type-button" style="display:none" name="attribute_height" data-attribute_name="attribute_height" data-show_option_none="yes"><option value="">Choose an option</option><option value="Regular(170-179cm)" class="attached enabled">Regular(170-179cm)</option><option value="Long(180-189cm)" class="attached enabled">Long(180-189cm)</option></select><ul role="radiogroup" aria-label="Height" class="variable-items-wrapper button-variable-wrapper" data-attribute_name="attribute_height" data-attribute_values="[&quot;Regular(170-179cm)&quot;,&quot;Long(180-189cm)&quot;]"><li aria-checked="false" data-wvstooltip="Regular(170-179cm)" class="variable-item button-variable-item button-variable-item-Regular(170-179cm)" title="Regular(170-179cm)" data-title="Regular(170-179cm)" data-value="Regular(170-179cm)" role="radio" tabindex="0"><div class="variable-item-contents"><span class="variable-item-span variable-item-span-button">Regular(170-179cm)</span></div></li><li aria-checked="false" data-wvstooltip="Long(180-189cm)" class="variable-item button-variable-item button-variable-item-Long(180-189cm)" title="Long(180-189cm)" data-title="Long(180-189cm)" data-value="Long(180-189cm)" role="radio" tabindex="0"><div class="variable-item-contents"><span class="variable-item-span variable-item-span-button">Long(180-189cm)</span></div></li></ul><a class="reset_variations" href="#" style="visibility: hidden;">Clear</a>                      </td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
```

Code for altered view, how I would like it to look like.

Is there a way to make this span element get rid from the code or make it invisible, so it's not making this bad looking gap between label of the table and button in it?

I was trying changing in styles:

```
.woo-selected-variation-item-name{
display:none;
height:0px;
}
```

But none of it works.

Comment: I highly recommend to startover from scratch. This is not tabular data and as such, a `<table>` is the wrong tool to start with. `<table>` is for tabular data only (with exeption fo e-mail templates)! The right tool to use would be either `flexbox` or `css-grid` while even `inline-block` would do the trick.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm confident enough to start from the scratches. I'm good with simple HTML/CSS edition but going deeper into wordpress backend is a bit scary. Anyway, thanks for the advice!

Comment: @tacoshy is right - for most cases, HTML tables are the wrong choice due to their built-in limitations/behaviours which are not intuitive at first. However, "write it again" is not an answer to the problem so unless it's impossible to achieve the desired result with the current setup, please avoid that kind of answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
font-size: 0;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
height: 0;
```

:)

EDIT: remember that all columns in the row must have that class in order to make sure that height will be 0

EDIT2: This solution made sure that your element is 0 height but parent `td.label` is still "high". I have added     `display: flex;` to it and now it seems to be working:

[image]

Also it would be great to align label a bit:

```
.woo-variation-swatches.wvs-show-label .variations td .woo-selected-variation-item-name, .woo-variation-swatches.wvs-show-label .variations td label {
  margin: 10px 0px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Wiktor for fast reply. Sadly, it's not working as well ;/

Comment: Hi @FilipMatyja, I have tried this CSS snippet on some random table on the w3schools site and it worked. If that doesn't work then there must be something else that prevents that "trick" from working. Can you share some codepen or link to your project so we can work on this together?

Comment: Sure sure, here you are mate. https://mancraftuk.com/product/gorka-4-anarok-digital

Comment: @FilipMatyja check out my edited comment :)

Comment: You are the star! Working like a charm. Many thanks Wiktor!